# Command: not, not working in html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to exclude the h2 element(inside the h2 div) so I can center the main title only. But when I use this command it aligns both titles to the center.

```css
.container:not(.h2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <div class="h2">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need to align only one element.

Comment: The selector `.container:not(.h2)` selects elements that have the class "container" but not the **class** "h2".

Answer (score 3):

To use this approach you'll need to use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`. This says "match the elements that are direct children of the `.container` class and do not have the `.h2` class"

```css
 .container > :not(.h2) {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <div class="h2">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your original CSS `.container:not(.h2)` is saying "select an element that has both the `.container` class and does not have the `.h2` class" - `.container` fits that so it applies the styles to the whole `div`.

In practice for this example you could just use `text-align: center;` on your `h1`, make different flexbox containers, or use more specific element selectors rather than using the parent `.container` class.